# SELECT FROM table WHERE lastupdated = most recently updated

Tags: php, mysql, select, timestamp

How do i select from table the most recently updated row.
My syntax seems to be wrong.

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  'table' WHERE lastupdated('timestamp') = CURDATE()")      or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
{
echo $row['name'] . "" .$row['phoneno'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: used order by lastupdated(your column name) desc and limit 1 it will give recent last updated record

Comment: use 'order by' command at the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the latest record which was last updated then you can
Try this::

```
SELECT * FROM  'table' order by lastupdated desc limit 1
```

Comment: Close.  Get rid of WHERE.

Comment: I have syntax error with this, it says I must check the manual that corresponds my MySQL server

Comment: And please explain, what is limit 1?

Comment: You should post the complete error message to get help, or check the manual yourself alone.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is to specify that you need only one row

Comment: Thanks got it, maybe I must read some timestamp manual, I also need to select second last updated and so on and on descending with the time.

Comment: @BlessingThinker: If you remove the `LIMIT 1` you will get the results order by the updated date

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT * FROM  'table' ORDER BY lastupdated DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @SashiKant `ID` is a auto increment column, OP may take another but he can use it for last record

Comment: Where was that specified that ID is autoincrement and how does that return the latest updated record, though it will return the last created record

Comment: Your assumptions about the order of auto_increment columns are wrong. The ID is not ordered. New entries do not automatically get the next highest number. Don't base any chronological order on an ID field.